# how to Managing activites for result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I just have 2 activites.

I want to go from activity1 to activity2 , do some jobs , then return result from activty2 to activity1

here is my code in activity1 :

```
Button otherkey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        otherkey.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(EncryptionActivity.this , FileExplore.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent3, 123);
                onActivityResult(123, Activity.RESULT_OK , intent3) ;//i think heres my problem.
            }});
```

and in the class of activity1 i have this method :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        System.out.println("req" + requestCode + "\nres code :"+resultCode);
        if (requestCode == 123) {
            if(resultCode == 0){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("mydata");
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
                System.out.println("ddd");
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
```

and the code in activity2 is :

```
                        activity2.this.finish();
                        Intent enca = new Intent();
                        enca.putExtra("mydata", "hello");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,enca);
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: You dont need to call `onActivityResult`  in your activity1, just call to `startActivityForResult`

Comment: don't call onActivityResult, it's a callback that will be called by a system

Comment: delete line in onClick that you mind it make problem ;) then it works

Comment: Aside: it's more common to use [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html), not `System.out.println`

Comment: thats ok now , but i always have the result 0 even i set the RESULT_OK , why this happened ?

Comment: Besides, I would call `finish` at the end of your snippet, not before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no need to call `onActivityResult` method but just simply `override` it. And will be called automatically when back to your activity. Check out this [link](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/) to understand more

```
public class TestActtiviy extends Activity{

    Button width, height, calc;
    TextView area;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     //your code
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //your code here
         if (resultCode == 0) {}

    }

}
```

Comment: i removed the line.
now when program wants to back from activity2 , has the error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=123, result=0, data=null} to activity

Comment: use `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){` instead of `if (requestCode == 123) {`